# Recognizing letters in grid with TextRecognize

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

Here is the test image:

[image: testcase]

You might recognize this as a [Boggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boggle) board. I want to translate the image into a 4x4 array of letters. Not quite sure how to deal with rotated letters and ambiguous letters yet ('M' vs. 'W') but one problem at a time. Here's what I've done.

```
testcaseEASY = my_img.jpg
bin = ChanVeseBinarize[testcaseEASY]
imgs = Flatten[ImagePartition[bin, ImageDimensions[bin][[1]]/4]];
```

Dividing the screen up into a 4x4 array manually is pretty dumb, it seems to work. So now I have a list of the letters, and they look pretty decent.

[image: O_unclean]

I try to make them look a bit better:

```
cleaner[img_] := ColorNegate[RemoveBackground[DeleteSmallComponents[img, 1000]]]
imgsCLEANED = Map[cleaner,imgs]
```

Now I get this:

[image: O_clean]

Why the ColorNegate? Not sure, it just gave the best results. Finally, I do

```
letters = {}; 
Do[AppendTo[letters, TextRecognize[imgsCLEANED[[i]], RecognitionPrior -> "Character"]], {i, 1, 16}];
MatrixForm[ArrayReshape[letters, {4, 4}]]
```

The output is

```
l   A   A   W
H   S   A   R
Y   T   H   B
    C   L   u
```

So it's pretty close but I'm obviously not quite there yet. Any ideas on how to improve this? I'm using Mathematica 12.0 if that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a decent result like this, but I had to replace "1" with "I" as TextRecognize has some difficulty with this font.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QkgN.jpg"];
adj = ImageResize[img, 256];
parts = ImagePartition[adj, 64];
extracted = Map[ColorNegate[DeleteBorderComponents[ColorNegate@Binarize[#]]] &, parts, {2}];
ImageAssemble[extracted]
Map[ToUpperCase[
    First[Characters[
       TextRecognize[#, RecognitionPrior -> "Character"]]] /. "1" -> "I"] &, extracted, {2}]//Grid
```

[image: boggle letters]

```
O   A   A   V
H   S   A   R
Y   T   H   B
I   C   L   U
```